# FireBase Crashlytics not reporting crash logs for signed apk (version wise)

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Firebase Crashlytics is reporting errors for debugging APK for all versions of the app but not showing for signed APK. I have updated the libraries required for the firebase crashlytics and Followed the tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android .Is there another way to get a crash report for debugging and signed versions separately?

**~/app/build.gradle**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
        apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
        
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 30
            buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.abc"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 30
                versionCode 24
                versionName "2.53"
                testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
        
            
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    applicationIdSuffix ".release"
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
        
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all { output ->
        
                    def project = "sample_App"
                    def SEP = "_"
                    def buildType =  variant.buildType.name
                    def version = variant.versionName
                    def newApkName = project + SEP + buildType + version + ".apk"
                    outputFileName = new File(newApkName)
                }
            }
        }
        
        dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
            implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
            implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
          
            // FireBase dependencies
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
        }
```